# mysql regular expression

Tags: mysql

I found this query in mysql query log and I will like to know what exactly does it do.

```
select * from tblname WHERE TRIM(NAME) REGEXP 'John[      ]*Smith'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It selects all rows from `tblname` where `name` (with spaces around removed, if any) equals to `John<any number of spaces>Smith`

So you'll find `JohnSmith` as well as `John_________________________Smith` (stackoverflow eats repetitive spaces, so I replaced them with underscore).

The regex itself is a little bloated and can be rewritten as `John *Smith`

Comment: You could even skip the character class :P